# Search box not displaying

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, catalogsearch

The native catalog search box does not display. I have it added to the local.xml file as

```
    <reference name=“left”>

    <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
```

So it displays in my sidebar. However it does not show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have change alias name and name of block
And here Complete code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<reference name="left">
            <block type="core/template" name="left.search" as="left.topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml" before="catalog.leftnav" />
        </reference>
</layout>
```

Comment: i've changed the alias to yours and refreshed cache yet nothing